# What kind of memory protections does Mac OSX 10.9 have compared to others?

Tags: macos, memory, selinux

I have a small project I work on in my free time that runs 32- and 64-bit assembler code from managed .NET assemblies based on the operating system I am on. You can see the techniques I use to get the shell code to run in the template, pretty basic stuff.

https://github.com/brandonprry/metafang2/blob/master/MetasploitPayloadUtility/GeneralTemplate.txt

The methods work on Windows and Linux just fine, but I expected the Unix way of executing the code would work on Mac and doesn't. With SELinux enabled (and I am sure other like pax and grsec), it does not achieve execution. This is totally expected though.

My question is, what does a Mac do to protect its memory? Does it have similar mechanisms like SELinux?

On an slight tangent, if it does, I was looking to implement something similar to the code at the bottom of this page to circumvent SELinux and to see if it worked on my Mac as well.

http://www.akkadia.org/drepper/selinux-mem.html